# ClassCastException

Tags: java, generics

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class CustomPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable {

private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;
private T[] elements;
private int size = 0;

/**
 * Constructs an isEmpty PriorityQueue with custom capacity.
 *
 * @param size
 */
CustomPriorityQueue(int size) {
    elements = (T[])  new Object[size];
}
```

Ошибка в конструкторе. Приравниваю неподходящие объекты. Не могу понять в чем проблема.
Comparable нужно для постройки бинарного дерева и его сортировки.

Comment: код ошибки  java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Comparable; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Comparable; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: `elements = new T[size];`

Comment: так нельзя. Пишет   Type parameter 'T' cannot be installed directly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

class CustomPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;
  private T[] elements;
  private int size = 0;

  CustomPriorityQueue(Class<T> clazz, int size) {
    elements = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
  }
}

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomPriorityQueue<Integer> q = new CustomPriorityQueue<>(Integer.class, 10);
  }
}
```

**Update**

Или так

```
elements = (T[]) new Comparable[size];
```